# Flutter - how to get the height and width of the AspectRatio widget?

Tags: flutter

```
AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: 1,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
```

I am trying to hand over AspectRatio's width and height to its child Container. I am trying to use this info to create the responsive Text widget. Is there any way that I can get the height and width of the AspectRatio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LayoutBuilder` to get the height and width of the `AspectRatio`. It is returned in terms of `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` of constraint.

```dart
AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: 1,
        child: LayoutBuilder(
               builder: (context, constraints) {

                  debugPrint(constraints.toString());
                  return Container(
                     color: Colors.blue,
                  );
               }
          ),
      ),
```

Comment: I was using `context.height` and didn't work. Cheers mate!

Comment: Cheers to the life with flutter.